# Is express-session not working with express 4.13?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, express-session

So I've set the session according to the [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/README.md) for express-session, as far as I can tell. But my cookie is not getting created!  According to the documentation, all you have to do is set the request.session value and the cookie should *automatically* be set. I'm not sure what voodoo enables this, but the magic seems to be broken. Just to be sure I verified against the example given [here](http://glebbahmutov.com/blog/express-sessions/). Am I wrong? Are these missing some key info?

```
   //login route handler
   app.post('/users/login/', function (req, res) {

   //... get the row from DB, check the pass then set session

   this.bcrypt.compare(password, row.hashed, function(err, passwordsMatch) {
            if( passwordsMatch === true)
            {
                //set the session variable 'user'
                req.session.user = row;
                res.send(row);
            }
        });
```

So I wonder am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug with the latest? I can check my database and I do see correct session variables on the rows in my session table!

```
//Here's my "configuration" of express-session. 
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    next();
});

var storeOptions = {
  //my database options (this works, it makes rows in db table)
};

var sessionStore = new SessionStore( storeOptions );

app.use(session({
    name:'yay_session',
    secret: 'some secret this is now',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { maxAge: 600000,httpOnly: false, domain:'localhost' },
    store: sessionStore
}));
```

Why is my client-side cookie not getting set? It does not show up in resources debug panel.  So I'm wondering if there's a bug with the latest 4.13.3 version working in tandem with express-session 1.11.3. This is latest as of Aug 27.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code for session to work normally in EXPRESS JS V 4: -

```
    var express = require('express');
    var session = require("express-session");
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var app = express();
    app.use(cookieParser());
    var MemoryStore =session.MemoryStore;
    app.use(session({
        name : 'app.sid',
        secret: "1234567890QWERTY",
        resave: true,
        store: new MemoryStore(),
        saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Comment: This problem wasted nearly a day for me. I thank you very much.

Comment: Please explain what you want to do. After trying this nothing was sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

The session must be saved.

```
req.session.save(function(err) {
  // session saved
})
```

More details on the [express-session page](https://github.com/expressjs/session).

Comment: Untrue, from the documentation: `This method is automatically called at the end of the HTTP response if the session data has been altered `